# opening multiple files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I open many files at same time in the python programming language to run my program?

I have about 15 files, just now I have worked with one of them
like below:

```
f=open("Exemplo_1.txt","rU")
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with opening multiple files, if you can open one of them?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a combination of `glob` and `fileinput`

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob

fnames = glob('Exemplo_*.txt')
for line in fileinput.input(fnames):
    pass # do whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f1=open("Exemplo_1.txt","rU");  
f2=open("Exemplo_2.txt","rU");  
...  
f15=open("Exemplo_15.txt","rU");
```

You're basically creating File objects to get access to the files.

Comment: If they don't need to be opened in parallel, I'd recommend using `with(open("Exemplo_1.txt", "rU")) as f1:` instead - the with keyword cleans up properly in the event of an exception.

Comment: Any chance that we could convince you to remove the semicolons ;-)

Comment: Using fifteen separate names for fifteen open files seems impractical.. unless each one is being treated differently, they're going to need to be put in something iterable anyway to avoid lots of code duplication.  I think it's probably a better idea to put them in a list or a dict.

Comment: Well I think Rohit Jain's comment on the question answers y'all :) and about Semicolon, @mgilson I don't want someone load SO with another question sayin `f=open(..)` not working in python! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this:

```
try:
    f = [open("Exemplo_%d.txt" % i, "rU") for i in range(1, 16)]
    # do stuff
finally:
    for fh in f:
        fh.close()
```

See [try/finally](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally).

Comment: This worked for me like a charm. I just want to understand the syntax though. %d and %i part...

Comment: I found this very useful. I needed to open 1000 files and write a random sample of a large dataset to each. The large dataset is much too large to fit into memory.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to loop over multiple files at one shot, use the fileinput module

```
for x in fileinput.input(['patterns.in', 'logfile.txt']):
    print x
```